определите вид придаточного
снова я и придаточные предложения.
заинтересовала меня такая конструкция: любая часть речи- это+придаточная часть.
пример: скука-это когда заняться нечем.
«когда заняться нечем» какой вид придаточного?понимаю, что это сказуемное скорее всего, а по другой классификации, в которой отсутствуют придаточные сказуемные?

Разбор предложения:
Скука — это когда заняться нечем.
1.Это простое предложение, в котором в роли именной части сказуемого выступает придаточное времени.
Сравнить: Скучно бывает, когда заняться нечем. Это СПП с придаточным времени.

Таке явление в синтаксисе называется контаминацией (смешением). В этом случае в роли члена предложения выступает предикативная единица (предложение).

Прочитать об этм можно в книге  Валгина Н.С.
Активные процессы в современном русском языке: Учебное
пособие для студентов вузов. - М.: Логос, 2003. - 304 с.  Стр. 208.
Также Розенталь, пункт 3: Самая поздняя осень — это когда от морозов рябина сморщится и станет, как говорят, «сладкой» (Пришв.) — в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение;

О придаточном предложении

Это односоставное инфинитивное предложение. Главный член инфинитивных предложений выражен независимым инфинитивом.
Кустова, стр. 92

снова спасибо!!!то есть это не будет спп?

Да, это не СПП. При разборе предложение считается простым (это старшая конструкция), а придаточное находится в позиции члена предложения (его статус понижен). Еще пример контаминации у Пушкина:  «Я думал уж о форме плана и как героя назову».  Здесь придаточное в роли однородного дополнения.  // Такие предложения не разбираются в школьных учебниках,  они ближе к фразеологии.  Надо сказать, что в разговорной речи вообще много фразеологических конструкций в области синтаксиса, в том числе с инфинитивами.

«я думал уж о форме плана и как героя назову» уже будет спп,правильно? оно будет придаточным изъяснительным у глаголу думал и по совместительству будет однородным дополнением вместе с «о форме плана»

Тут интересный момент. Если мы делаем синтаксический разбор, то прежде всего должны решить: это простое предложение или сложное? Вроде бы оно кажется СПП, ведь есть главная часть и есть придаточная. Но так ли это?  Среди СПП такого синтаксиса не найдешь. И вот думается мне, что это простое предложение с однородными дополнениями, а придаточное просто приравнивается к члену предложения (второму дополнению). Об этом свидетельствует пунктуация и произношение.   Вы можете согласиться с таким решением или что-то кажется вам нелогичным?

все таки мне кажется, что это придаточно.я наверное запуталась… а в моем примере про скуку,придаточное будет именное времени,не сказуемное?но при этом оно служит именной частью сказуемого,а другие придаточные в своем обычном виде служат просто придаточнмыи? а еще хотела спросить про предложение «мне кажется девочка выиграет» будет ли оно придаточным и тут будто опущен союз «что»

Ответ на комментарий

Я думал уж (о чем?) о форме плана и как героя назову. Это простое предложение с однородными членами, но в позиции второго члена находится придаточное. Фразеологическая модель   предложения.

Сравнить:
(1) Я думал уж о форме плана и об имени героя. Простое предложение.
(2) Я думал уж, каким будет общий план и как героя назову.
СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными. Других вариантов для СПП нет, для однородных отношений нужны два придаточных.
Но это факультативная тема, надо сначала хорошо освоить базовый материл.

Скука — это когда заняться нечем.

Это придаточное времени в позиции именной части сказуемого. Об этом можно судить по временному союзу, но никаких временных отношений придаточное не обозначает, так как это не СПП.
Сказуемное придаточное – это термин из темы  местоименно- определительных придаточных, например: Каково лето, таково и сено.  Местоимение таково является сказуемым.
Это тоже факультативная тема.

Мне кажется, девочка выиграет.

Это БСП (бессоюзное предложение) с изъяснительными отношениями. Такое предложение  имеет аналог среди СПП: Мне кажется, что девочка выиграет. Но это разные предложения, нельзя говорить, что союз пропущен.
Вывод. Надо хорошо знать базовые модели СПП и БСП, а фразеологию лучше изучать потом. А иначе действительно запутаешься.
